# Deleting a row based on two conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

So I have a row of data in a sheet. I need to delete the row if column H = "Complete" and if Column A's timestamp is more than 48 hours old. My issue is with adding in the elapse time condition. The script works when deleting the row if column H = "Complete".

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID");
var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
var day = 24*3600*1000
var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);


var DELETE_VAL = "Complete";
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 7; // The column to search for the DELETE_VAL (Zero is first)
var COL_TO_SEARCH_2 = 0; // The column to search for the date (Zero is first)


function deleteEachRow(){

  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();

  //Reverse the 'for' loop.
  for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] === DELETE_VAL && rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH_2] < today){

      SHEET.deleteRow(i+1); 
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function deleteIfOlderThan2DaysAgo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dt=new Date();
  var twoDaysAgo=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-2).valueOf();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var col1=new Date(vA[i][0]).valueOf();
    if(vA[i][7]=="Complete" && col1<twoDaysAgo) {
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey !! Thank you for your assistance. It doesn't appear to be working. Could it be due to the time format i am using? (ex. 9/15/2019 13:29:39)

Comment: No I had an error in it.  Copy it now.  It's working.  That format should be ok.

Comment: For my edification. Does the change to not specify the sheet and tab mean that this will apply to the whole sheet? If for instance there was another tab on the same sheet with a similar format that I didn't want this to apply to would it?

Comment: Oh yeh.  I forgot to change that back.  Now it's in there.

Comment: In answer to your question.  It would apply to the active sheet whatever it is.  But using the openById() implies you would be running it on the server so the active page will always be the left most page.  (i.e. getSheets()[0])

Comment: (TypeError: Cannot call method "openById" of undefined. (line 2, file "Delete Row")) Not sure if it would help to link the sheet.

Comment: That works marvelously. I doubt I would have figured out how to reference that time correctly. Now i just need to figure out how to set a default value for data validation. Off to google some more. Thank you so much :D